# ExtJS 4: How to know when any field in a form (Ext.form.Panel) changes?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'd like a single event listener that fires whenever *any* field in a form (i.e., Ext.form.Panel) changes. The Ext.form.Panel class doesn't fire an event for this itself, however.

What's the best way to listen for 'change' events for all fields in a form?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Update**: Added a 3rd option based on tip in comments (thanks @innerJL!)*

Ok, looks like there are *at least* two fairly simple ways to do it.

**Option 1)** Add a 'change' listener to each field that is added to the form:

```
Ext.define('myapp.MyFormPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  alias: 'myapp.MyFormPanel',
  ...

  handleFieldChanged: function() { 
    // Do something
  },

  listeners: {
    add: function(me, component, index) {
      if( component.isFormField ) {
        component.on('change', me.handleFieldChanged, me);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This has at least one big drawback; if you "wrap" some fields in other containers and then add those containers to the form, it won't recognize the nested fields. In other words, it doesn't do a "deep" search through the component to see if it contains form field that need 'change' listeners.

**Option 2)** Use a component query to listen to all 'change' events fired from fields in a container.

```
Ext.define('myapp.MyController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  ...

  init: function(application) {
    me.control({

        '[xtype="myapp.MyFormPanel"] field': {
            change: function() {
              // Do something
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

**Option 3)** Listen for the 'dirtychange' fired from the form panel's underlying 'basic' form (Ext.form.Basic). **Important**: You need to make sure you must enable 'trackResetOnLoad' by ensuring that {trackResetOnLoad:true} is passed to your form panel constructor.

```
Ext.define('myapp.MyFormPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  alias: 'myapp.MyFormPanel',
  constructor: function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    config.trackResetOnLoad = true;
    me.callParent([config]);

    me.getForm().on('dirtychange', function(form, isDirty) {
       if( isDirty ) {
            // Unsaved changes exist
        }
        else {
            // NO unsaved changes exist
        }
    });
  }
});
```

This approach is the "smartest"; it allows you to know when the form has been modified, but also if the user modifies it back to it's original state. For example, if they change a text field from "Foo" to "Bar", the 'dirtychange' event will fire with 'true' for the isDirty param. But if the user then changes the field *back* to "Foo", the 'dirtychange' event will fire *again* and isDirty will be *false*.

Comment: maybe this event of BasicForm (yourForm.getForm()) might be useful for you http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-event-dirtychange

Comment: If anyone has a solution for ExtJs 3 I'd be interested.

Comment: Be careful with 3rd option. Listener will be triggered only when `isDirty` property of the form changes. That means if you have textfield with value "Foo" and user changes that value to "Bar" — `dirtychange` will be triggered. But if user change value again to "Pool"  `dirtychange` will NOT be triggered because `isDirty` property is already `true`

Answer (score 7):

I want to complement Clint's answer. There is one more approach (and I think it's the best for your problem). Just add `change` listener to form's defaults config:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    // ...
    defaults: {
        listeners: {
            change: function(field, newVal, oldVal) {
                //alert(newVal);
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! In my case I actually do need a custom class that extends form panel; also I only want to know when a field is changed from its original value ('dirtychange' vs. 'change') but this might be great advice for other scenarios where those two requirements don't apply.

Comment: There is no such change event in form panel, nor does it listen to it.

Comment: @Marshal. I didn't write that form has such event. Form fields have such events. In my example handler was NOT assigned to form. It was assigned to all fields of the form. See the [defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-defaults) config.

Comment: You should use `fieldDefaults` instead which will properly propagate to field groups.